# Nginx Remove Trailing Question Mark

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule in Nginx to remove trialing question mark (`?`) from urls but i can't get it right. I've done that for trailing slashes like this:

```
#redirect all trailing slash URL's to the respective non trailing slash
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

so I figured the same would work just replacing the slash with the question mark:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)?$ /$1 permanent;
```

but that didn't work, but it occurred to me that the question mark has some significance in the regex so i tried escaping it:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\?$ /$1 permanent;
```

but that didn't work either, I tried also removing the first slash:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\?$ $1 permanent;
```

but that was also a bust, and yes i did restart the server in between tests.

Here's what I am trying to do:

- `www.mysite.com?` should redirect to `wwww.mysite.com`
- `www.mysite.com/some/path?` should redirect to `wwww.mysite.com/some/path`
- `www.mysite.com?some=vars` should remain unchanged.
- `www.mysite.com/some/path?some=vars` should remain unchanged.

so basically only removing the question mark if there is no query string. 
How can i accomplish that?

I've checked other answers but they seem to want to remove the query string entirely, I only want to remove in the case that there is only a question mark and no parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` marks the start of the query string and is not part of the normalized URI used by the `rewrite` or `location` directives. So you cannot remove it using a `rewrite` statement.

You will need to look at the original request which is in the `$request_uri` variable.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\?$) { return 301 $1; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.